# javascript addEventListener Registering multiple events in OOPS

Tags: javascript, events, addeventlistener

```
function myclass(){
 var _d =document,_w = window,self=myclass;

var addEvent = function (el,e,callback,capture){
    var evt = _w.event;
    if(_w.addEventListener){
      el.addEventListener(e,callback,capture);         
    }else el.attachEvent("on"+e,callback,capture); 

   }
   var removeEvent = function (el,e,callback){ console.log("rmv")
      if(window.removeEventListener)
       el.removeEventListener(e,callback);
    else el.detachEvent("on"+e,callback);
 }

 function startWork(params){
  self.cfUrl  = params.createfolder || ""; 
   var cf = select('[data-action="createfolder"]');
    addEvent(cf,'click',mymethod);   

  }      
  return {         
    addEvent:addEvent,
    init:startWork,
    removeEvent:removeEvent,
 };   
 }
```

When I click on registered element using my `Javascript` oop's menthod it run the event how many times I clicked on element?

e.g: Click on create folder link and then click on create button how many time you click on create folder link. a request post same times.

Here is full code jsFiddle code link : https://jsfiddle.net/pm6bs5x9/

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: see example :-https://jsfiddle.net/pm6bs5x9/

just click on  "create folder" link 2 times and then click on button "create" then see in browser console it trigger XHR requests how many times. it will trigger request how many times you clicked on  link.

Comment: If I get you right, you want a situation such that if you click on the link more than once, it only calls the XHR only once, am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Here is solution 

 Don`t use anonymous function with addEventListener

 eg. addEvent(clear,"click",function(){
     //your code...
     }); 
  use 
   var CreateFolder = function (e){    
    var form = select(".form-create_folder"),
    clear = select(".form-create_folder a");
    form.style.top ="10px";
    addEvent(clear,"click",upit);  
    addEvent(form,'submit',submitit);   
   }
  function upit(e){ //your code }
  function submitit(e){ //your code }



 use separate handler with name as mentioned above...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly disable the "create folder" button until the request is complete. Then on request complete, you reactivate the button. Basically, you get a reference to the button like the below contrived example:

```
var btn = document.getElementById(buttonID);
btn.disabled =true;
```

Then on successful return of XHR, you re-enable the button by doing this:

```
btn.disabled = false;
```

The reason for all this is that the element has no way of telling that you want it to fire only once. So, once you've attached the listener to the element, it knows to listen for every event of its assigned type, no matter how many times that event occurs.

To prevent it, you have to explicitly instruct it to not respond to any further requests until the current requested is complete. This you do by disabling it until the current request has returned.

Comment: Have you seen the example link. it is not like what you understood.look  examle click on "create folder" link 2,3,4,5,6 times and the type any value in  textbox then click on "Create" button , you can see how many times you clicked on "create folder" link. the addeventlistener trigger function that much times.....

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the event listener after the first call.

Call the `removeEvent()` function inside the callback function itself, but you have to use an external function as a callback because with an ananymous function you the removeEventListener will not work as stated in the **[removeEventListener() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeeventlistener.asp)** documentation.

This is a simple use case example:

```js
var _d = document,
  _w = window;

var addEvent = function(el, e, callback, capture) {
  var evt = _w.event;
  if (_w.addEventListener) {
    el.addEventListener(e, callback, capture);
  } else el.attachEvent("on" + e, callback, capture);

}
var removeEvent = function(el, e, callback) {
  console.log("rmv")
  if (window.removeEventListener)
    el.removeEventListener(e, callback);
  else el.detachEvent("on" + e, callback);
}


var increment = function increment() {
  var inc = document.getElementById("inc");
  inc.value = parseInt(inc.value) + 1;
}

var clickme = document.getElementById("clickme");
addEvent(clickme, 'click', increment);


var increment2 = function increment2() {
  var inc2 = document.getElementById("inc2");
  inc2.value = parseInt(inc2.value) + 1;
  //Remove the event inside your callback
  removeEvent(clickme2, 'click', increment2);
}

var clickme2 = document.getElementById("clickme2");
addEvent(clickme2, 'click', increment2);
```

```html
<p><h3>Without calling removeEvent</h3></p>
<input type="button" id="clickme" value="Click me!" />
<input type="text" id="inc" value="0" />

<p><h3>With removeEvent</h3></p>
<input type="button" id="clickme2" value="Click me once!" />
<input type="text" id="inc2" value="0" />
```

And you just need to adopt the same logic in your example.

Comment: this is not exact solution of my question. what i am using Object Oriented Javascript. in that what i need to do.

Comment: It's the same logic and the same thing, you just need to rearrange your code so you can remove the event listener.

Comment: i tried what you mentioned above but it it not working with my class. i have made changes in html see updated link :- https://jsfiddle.net/pm6bs5x9/3/